# AnyLogic stop simulation: finish()

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to stop my anylogic model during setup.
I tried to use `getEngine().finish()` or `getEngine().pause()` but is seems like these functions only work when the simulation is already running. In my case, I am trying to handle a situation where I need to finish the simulation at the begging (during model initiation) when `getEngine().getState()` is still at `PLEASE_WAIT`.
Any thoughts?

getEngine().finish() and finishSimulation()

Comment: so you want to finish the simulation before it starts.. why?

Comment: Yes. Because of invalid inputs

Comment: I ended up handling this with java:   System.exit(0)